# Exception при использовании ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android

Мой код

```
String url = "http://sound.andviro.pw:8443/slife/sample.mp3";
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackFactory);
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);


    DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);

    playerControl.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
```

При запуске, получаю такую ошибку. Что делать? и о чем ошибка

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\254.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\256.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\257.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\258.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\440.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\441.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\442.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\443.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\444.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\445.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\446.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\447.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\448.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\449.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\450.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\451.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\452.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\453.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\454.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\455.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\456.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\457.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\458.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\459.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\460.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\461.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\462.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\463.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\464.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\465.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\466.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\467.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\468.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\469.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\470.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\495.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\496.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\497.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\498.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\499.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\254.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\256.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\257.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\258.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\440.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\441.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\442.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\443.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\444.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\445.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\446.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\447.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\448.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\449.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\450.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\451.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\452.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\453.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\454.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\455.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\456.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\457.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\458.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\459.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\460.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\461.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\462.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\463.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\464.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\465.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\466.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\467.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\468.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\469.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\470.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\495.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\496.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\497.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\498.jar, C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJava\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\499.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 56 more
```

---

```
    Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$ViewElevationComparator
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$ViewElevationComparator, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Comment: а что за либы `254.jar` и проч?

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что Studio 3.2 / gradle plugin 3.1+  и там уже по умолчанию D8 включен, соответсвенно попробуйте [следующее](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#D8) :

> D8 shouldn't change your day-to-day app development workflow. However, if you experience any issues related to the new compiler,
>   please report a bug. You can temporarily disable D8 and use DX by
>   including the following in your project's gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableD8=false
```

Comment: не помогло/ испльзую `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'`